# не работает видео-стрим webrtc

Tags: потоки-данных, webrtc

Создаю медиа приложение на основе webrtc на фреймворке adonis. Приложение для ведения стрима. Архитектуру выбрал такую: 
стример (webrtc)-> сервер (webrtc)-> зрители.
По началу решил реализовать тест, который возвращает поток обратно стримеру:
стример (webrtc)-> сервер (webrtc)-> стример.
Соединение создается, По каналу данных(RTCDataChannel) данные передаются, но видео связь никак не удается поднять. Что я делаю не так?
Вот реализация схемы стример (webrtc)-> сервер (webrtc)-> стример:

index.html

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.4.4/polyfill.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@adonisjs/websocket-client"></script>
  <script src='index.js'></script>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

index.js

```js
let connection = new RTCPeerConnection({ //экземпляр RTCPeerConnection
  sdpSemantics: 'unified-plan',
  iceServers: [ // Information about ICE servers
    {
      urls: "stun:stun.stunprotocol.org"
    }
  ]
});

connection.onicecandidate = async function({
  candidate
}) { //событие появления ice кандидата
  socket.emit('candidate', candidate)
}
connection.ontrack = function(e) { //это не работает(
  console.log('track!')
}



const Ws = adonis.Ws('ws://localhost:3333').connect(); //Соединяемся к серверу по WebSocket (реализация adonis)
let socket = Ws.subscribe("connections"); // Подписываемся на канал "connections"
// Ws.on("open", () => {
// });
socket.on('candidate', async(candidate) => { //событие приема ice кандидата от сервера
  //console.log(1,candidate)
  if (candidate) {
    await connection.addIceCandidate(candidate)
  }
})
socket.on('sdp', async(answer) => { //событие приема sdp ответа от сервера
  await connection.setRemoteDescription(answer)
})


let remoteVideo
let localVideo
let localStream


async function f() { //установить на странице объекты <video>, привязав к ним потоки
  localVideo = document.createElement('video');
  localVideo.autoplay = true;
  localVideo.muted = true;

  remoteVideo = document.createElement('video');
  remoteVideo.autoplay = true;

  const videos = document.createElement('div');
  videos.className = 'grid';
  videos.appendChild(localVideo);
  videos.appendChild(remoteVideo);
  window.onload = function() {
    document.body.appendChild(videos);
  }

  localStream = await window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true
  })

  localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => connection.addTrack(track, localStream));
  localVideo.srcObject = localStream;
  const remoteStream = new MediaStream(connection.getReceivers().map(receiver => receiver.track));
  remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;
}

// ---------------------Тест канала данных - нужно для проверки соедининия---------
let dc = connection.createDataChannel("channel");

dc.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log("received: " + event.data);
};


connection.ondatachannel = function(e) {
  dc = e.channel
  dc.send('to Server')
}
// ---------------------Тест канала данных - нужно для проверки соедининия---------


async function connect() {
  let offer = await connection.createOffer({ //создаем offer
    offerToReceiveAudio: true,
    offerToReceiveVideo: true
  })
  await connection.setLocalDescription(offer)
  socket.emit('sdp', offer) //отправляем серверу
}


f()
connect()
```

server.js(условно(структура adonis))

```js
'use strict'

const RTCPeerConnection = require('wrtc').RTCPeerConnection;


class ConnectionController { //реализация adonis
  constructor({
    socket,
    request
  }) {
    this.socket = socket
    this.request = request


    this.connection = new RTCPeerConnection({ //экземпляр RTCPeerConnection
      configuration: {
        offerToReceiveAudio: true,
        offerToReceiveVideo: true
      },
      sdpSemantics: 'unified-plan',
      iceServers: [ // Information about ICE servers - Use your own!
        {
          urls: "stun:stun.stunprotocol.org"
        }
      ]
    })


    this.connection.onicecandidate = async({
      candidate
    }) => { //событие появления ice кандидата
      this.socket.emit('candidate', candidate)
    }
    this.connection.ontrack = function(e) { //это не работает(
      console.log('track!')
    }

    // ---------------------Тест канала данных - нужно для проверки соедининия---------
    let dc = this.connection.createDataChannel("channel");
    dc.onmessage = function(event) {
      console.log("received: " + event.data);
    };
    this.connection.ondatachannel = function(e) {
      dc = e.channel
      dc.send('to Client')
    }
    // ---------------------Тест канала данных - нужно для проверки соедининия---------


    //создать петлю для перенаправления стрима обратно
    const audioTransceiver = this.connection.addTransceiver('audio');
    const videoTransceiver = this.connection.addTransceiver('video');
    console.log(audioTransceiver.receiver.track)
    Promise.all([
      audioTransceiver.sender.replaceTrack(audioTransceiver.receiver.track),
      videoTransceiver.sender.replaceTrack(videoTransceiver.receiver.track)
    ]);



  }


  async onCandidate(candidate) { //событие приема ice кандидата от сервера
    if (candidate) {
      await this.connection.addIceCandidate(candidate)
    }
  }

  async onSdp(offer) { //событие приема sdp ответа от сервера
    await this.connection.setRemoteDescription(offer)
    let answer = await this.connection.createAnswer()
    await this.connection.setLocalDescription(answer)
    this.socket.emit('sdp', answer)
  }

}

module.exports = ConnectionController
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался! Проблема была в том, что addTrack нужно вызывать до offer-а. Асинхронность js сыграла против меня, из-за чего последовательность вызовов была нарушена и как следствие система не заводилась